# Error 999999 with topo to raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error-999999

I'm trying to create a raster from contours and some points with an elevation field but when I excecute I get this error :

```
Executing: TopoToRaster "pts_drones ELEVATION PointElevation;courbes_5m 
CONTOUR Contour" "F:\Data interpolation\DEM" 10 courbes_5m 20 # # ENFORCE 
CONTOUR 20 # 1 0 2.5 100 # # # # # # # #
Start Time: Wed Feb 28 09:48:15 2018
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to open raster dataset
Failed to execute (TopoToRaster).
Failed at Wed Feb 28 09:48:22 2018 (Elapsed Time: 6.61 seconds)
```

the picture below describes my process : 
[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the output surface raster as:

```
F:\DataInterpolation\Dem.tif
```

Always avoid spaces in paths, and specify the format of the target file (in this case .tif) at the end of the output path